# Cron Job Console Connect and Root Permissions

Tags: shell-script, permissions, cron, console

I'm working on a script for user Bob with the relevant parts shown below. Problem I'm having is if I put this cronjob under user Bob, zenity will work but shutdown wont. And if I put it under root shutdown will work but zenity won't be visible on console.

```
#!/bin/bash
eval "export $(egrep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$(pgrep -u Bob gnome-session)/environ)";
someValue=`DISPLAY=:0.0 zenity --text="tell me your value" --entry`
...
...
/sbin/shutdown -h "now"
```

I also tried running under root and using su to Bob for zenity and exiting back to root to shutdown, but that didn't work.

Is there a way to do this?

Other info

OS is Linux Mint and Bob is the only user of the machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-privileged users cannot shutdown a machine from command line. If you absolutely need to send shutdown as Bob, you can add him to sudoers using `visudo`.

```
sudo visudo
```

Add the following line to is:

```
bob ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown -h "now"
```

Save file. Then you can `su` as bob and test the command:

```
sudo /sbin/shutdown -h "now"
```